# I need help finding the linear equation for an exponential regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I've done nearly everything but at the end when I need to $\alpha$ it doesn't work and I'm not sure what's wrong. This is the function:

$y = \alpha\beta^x$

I transformed it into a linear equation and I get this:

$ln(y) = ln(\alpha)+xln(\beta)$

After all that stuff, I changed my data points, which are these:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
X &-4 &-2 &3 &5 &7\\ \hline
Y &ln(50)&ln(30)&ln(10)&ln(6)&ln(2)
\end{array}

After doing a bunch of calculations this is what I got for everything:

$\sum x = 9$

$\sum y = 12.1$

$\sum xy = -1.732$

$\sum x^2 = 103$

$\sum y^2 = 35.865$

So I do all that and find that

$\beta = e^{-0.2709} = 0.7627$

Then I try to use this formula

$\alpha = \hat{y} -\beta\hat{x} $

But I get the wrong answer, can anyone help me out, I've no clue as to why I can't get $\alpha$. It is supposed to be $18.3154$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the problem $Y=a +b x$ where $Y_i=\log(y_i)$. Compute $a,b$ as usual and $\alpha=e^a$, $\beta=e^b$. Your last formula is not correct.

Comment: You seem to be confusing $y$ and $\ln y$. You have $\ln y=2.9-0.27\ln x$. That translates into $y=18\times 0.76^x$. My numbers are rough.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, I wish you'd have put it as an answer though, so I could have given you the points or whatever.